# Matlab: Argmax and dot product for each row in a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, dot-product

I have 2 matrices = `X in R^(n*m)` and `W in R^(k*m)` where `k<<n`.
Let `x_i` be the i-th row of X and `w_j` be the j-th row of W.
I need to find, for each x_i what is the j that maximizes `<w_j,x_i>`

I can't see a way around iterating over all the rows in X, but it there a way to find the maximum dot product without iterating every time over all of W?

A naive implementation would be:

```
n = 100;
m = 50;
k = 10;
X = rand(n,m);
W = rand(k,m);
Y = zeros(n, 1);

for i = 1 : n
  max_ind = 1;
  max_val = dot(W(1,:), X(i,:));
  for j = 2 : k
       cur_val = dot(W(j,:),X(i,:));

       if cur_val > max_val
          max_val = cur_val;
          max_ind = j;
       end

   end

   Y(i,:) = max_ind;
end
```

Comment: Share the *iterating* code with us? Also add an example case maybe?

Comment: I've added the naive implementation that I can come up with

Comment: +1 for reproducible example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dot product is essentially matrix multiplication:

```
[~, Y] = max(W*X');
```

Comment: @Divakar Thanks :-) Your `bsxfun` is nice too (+1 already), and takes about the same time

Comment: Oh I doubt that, especially with large datasets, `bsxfun` has to get slower.

Answer (score 2):

[**`bsxfun`**](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) based approach to speed-up things for you -

```
[~,Y] = max(sum(bsxfun(@times,X,permute(W,[3 2 1])),2),[],3)
```

On my system, using your dataset I am getting a `100x+` speedup with this.

---

One can think of two more "closeby" approaches, but they don't seem to give any huge improvement over the earlier one -

```
[~,Y] = max(squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@times,X,permute(W,[3 2 1])),2)),[],2)
```

and

```
[~,Y] = max(squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@times,X',permute(W,[2 3 1]))))')
```